# App runs fine on heroku, except for one problem

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have an application that allows people to look up their government representatives using an address. When it is connected to a local mongo db it works perfectly. I am using the db to store like/dislikes on the reps page. The problem is that I added the documents in the db manually and so it doesn't/cant track likes on heroku, since the db isnt create dynamically in the code. That didn't seem like too much of a problem though. I would just create the exact same documents in Atlas db, right? Well here I am several hours later and Im pulling my hair out. 
I have never used Atlas but it seems straightforward. Use their url to connected to your cluster/db. Thats about it from what I can tell. Problem is, I can get an empty array back from a return all route... and thats it. I have two docs in the db currently and need them to track my likes/dislikes. Im just not sure where to go from here and have to deploy this by tomorrow evening. Please help

I have reformatted the url six ways to Sunday. I have moved around code in server to try and diagnose the problem and I have messed with my routes. Ive tried postman and am getting an array back but thats it. I added a console.log in server that returns my cluster so I know Im connected in some capacity.
Sorry if Im missing something obvious and didn't show enough code, I am fairly new to all this if you cant tell. Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

`````
````const routes = require("./routes");
````const app = express();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
````const mongoose = require("mongoose")
````const bodyParser = require("body-parser")


````//Bodyparser middleware
````app.use(bodyParser.json());

````//DB config 

````const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
````const uri = "mongodb+srv://NicoP93:REDACTED@cluster0-vplwy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"
````MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
    ````if(err){
        ````console.log("Not connected to atlas")
    ````} else {
        ````console.log("connected to atlas")
    ````}
    ````const collection = client.db("Overthrow").collection("Knowledge")
    ````if(collection){console.log("Collection Connection")};
    ````console.log(collection);

````mongoose.connect(uri).then(() => {console.log("Mongoose connected")})
````})

 ````const items = require("./routes/api/items")
 ````app.use('/api/items', items);

````const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
````app.use(express.urlencoded({
    ````extended: true
````}));
````app.use(express.json());

````if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    ````app.use(express.static("client/build"));
````}

````app.use(routes);


````app.listen(PORT, function () {
````    console.log("  ==> API Server now listening on port " + PORT);
````});

When I hit the get all route I would expect something like 
{"_id:5cd9fff41c9d440000f25cb8
buttonLike:0
buttonDislike:0
representativeName:"Ted Cruz"
__v:"0"} 
because thats what in my atlas db, Im looking at it right now in their website. 

Additionally, node server returns:

{(node:5600) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
  ==> API Server now listening on port 3001
connected to atlas
Collection Connection
Collection {
  s:
   { pkFactory:
      { [Function: ObjectID]
        index: 550824,
        createPk: [Function: createPk],
        createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
        createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
        isValid: [Function: isValid],
        ObjectID: [Circular],
        ObjectId: [Circular] },
     db:
      Db {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        s: [Object],
        serverConfig: [Getter],
        bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
        databaseName: [Getter] },
     topology:
      ReplSet {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 25,
        _maxListeners: Infinity,
        clientInfo: [Object],
        s: [Object] },
     dbName: 'Overthrow',
     options:
      { promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
        readConcern: undefined,
        readPreference: [ReadPreference] },
     namespace: 'Overthrow.Knowledge',
     readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'primary', tags: undefined },
     slaveOk: true,
     serializeFunctions: undefined,
     raw: undefined,
     promoteLongs: undefined,
     promoteValues: undefined,
     promoteBuffers: undefined,
     internalHint: null,
     collectionHint: null,
     name: 'Knowledge',
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     readConcern: undefined,
     writeConcern: undefined } }
     Mongoose connected                }
`````

Comment: Your title is the Stack Overflow equivalent of [a "one weird trick" link](https://slate.com/business/2013/07/how-one-weird-trick-conquered-the-internet-what-happens-when-you-click-on-those-omnipresent-ads.html). It tells us absolutely nothing; its only purpose is to trick people into clicking on it. That's bad writing in general, and _awful_ on Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and give us a decent title.

Comment: Also, your code block is all messed up. What's with the four backticks (`\``) prefixing every line? That's invalid syntax. We shouldn't have to guess which errors are relevant and which are typos. Please fix your code.

Comment: Finally, your question is buried in a mass of text. Even after digging around to find it you haven't given us a very clear problem statement. What do "I can get an empty array back from a return all route... and thats it" and "Ive tried postman and am getting an array back but thats it" mean? Are you talking about the response from MongoDB or from your web application? If the latter, have you verified that MongoDB is giving you the expected data? Ideally, we'd like you to provide a [mcve].